# why are content going off screen

Tags: html, css

As my title suggests, my content goes off screen.

I've looked through my css file, and there's isn't any margins with minus something. So why is the content going off screen at both sides?

Appreciate any suggestions to why this is.

Thanks.

```css
body{
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(100,50,50), rgb(80,20,20)) no-repeat;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}



img{
    margin: 1%;
}


/*Header*/
header {
  background-color: #1d1e21;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

header span {
  color: #fff;
}

header input {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

p#slogan  {
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}



/*Main*/

/*sloganAndSocial*/
#sloganAndSocial {
  background-color: #1d1e21;
  position: absolute;
  
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>NBC 2011</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<!--Header section-->
        <header>
            <div id="topBar">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h1 class="pull-left"><span>NORDIC </span>BARISTACUP</h1>
                        <form class="pull-right">
                            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="pull-left" id="slogan">be together &nbsp; act together &nbsp; learn together</p>
                        <ul class="pull-right">
                            <li><a href="#">ABOUT NBV</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2011 EVENT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">NORDIC ROASTER</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">RESULTS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>

<!--Main section-->
            <div class="main">
                <img src="" alt="bo!" class="cover" /> 
            </div>

            <div id="sloganAndSocial">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h2 class="pull-left">"To create an environment in which knowledge<br>about coffee and its sphere can be obtained"</h2>
                        <ul class="share-buttons">
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=&t=a" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank"><img alt="Share on Facebook" src="images/flat_web_icon_set/inverted/Facebook.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=&text=a:%20" target="_blank" title="Tweet"><img alt="Tweet" src="images/flat_web_icon_set/inverted/Twitter.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"><img alt="Share on Google+" src="images/flat_web_icon_set/inverted/Google+.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=&description=a" target="_blank" title="Pin it"><img alt="Pin it" src="images/flat_web_icon_set/inverted/Pinterest.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="mailto:?subject=a&body=a:%20" target="_blank" title="Send email"><img alt="Send email" src="images/flat_web_icon_set/inverted/Email.png"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
    </header>

             
        

<!--Section1-->
        

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.row` has negative margins on it which is causing the bleed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `divs` in your `topBar` with class `row` but which are not inside an element with class `container`. That is not intended by `Bootstrap` and therefore leads to unintended behaviour. You have to wrap those two `divs` in another `div` with class `container`.

Also, as @nik_m mentioned: Why are you wrapping the whole page in a `header`? That's not, what `headers` are supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know it what necessary to use the container class. The code is just a small part of a website. So I am not wrapping it in a header. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `pull-left` and `pull-right` classes from the elements and better use [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for your alignments. It will make your life much easier!

Also, why the wrapper of the whole site is inside a `header`???

Comment: That doesn't work. It just centers the text. I'm not wrapping the whole site in a header. The code I posted is only a part of a site.

Comment: OK. Didn't know that was a part of your site. Nevertheless, you should sometime learn flexbox. Its more modular, you can do exactly what you want and most of all its very straightforward! Cheers!